# Why has my program "stopped" working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a program to calculate pi (just as a bit of fun, I don't want to use the pi that's built in) in Python 3.3.2. It works fine - it gets the correct value of pi up to 7 decimal places. However, once it gets to this point, the program continues but the values do not change. I have tried using decimal.Decimal, but it does not work - it comes up with the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

This is my working code (using floats instead of decimals.) I have only included the actual algorithm :

```
pi=float(3)
a=2
b=0
c=float(0)
while 1==1:
    b=a*(a+1)*(a+2)
    c=4/b
    pi=pi+c
    print(str(pi))
    a=a+2
    b=a*(a+1)*(a+2)
    c=4/b
    pi=pi-c
    print(str(pi))
    a=a+2
```

And this is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwGxk.png (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images directly)

Please note that the program actually stopped working much earlier than this, I just left it there for a while. 
I know that the algorithm that I am using is capable of finding pi to many more decimal places, so can someone please tell me why it is not working, and give me any possible solutions?
As you might notice from the simplicity of my code that I am not too good at python - only the basic knowledge that I have been taught at school. Simple solutions would be much appreciated! 
EDIT
This is the non-working code with Decimal, and Jasper's suggestion in it. 
   `import decimal
    pi=decimal.Decimal(3)
    a=2
    b=0
    c=decimal.Decimal(0)
    while True:
        b=a*(a+1)*(a+2)
        c=4/b
        pi=pi+c
        print(str(pi))
        a=a+2
        b=a*(a+1)*(a+2)
        c=4/b
        pi=pi-c
        print(str(pi))
        a=a+2`
This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users...\fastpi2.py", line 9, in 
>   pi=pi+c TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

Comment: `while 1==1` should be `while True`. If you use `Decimal`, you have to use it everywhere consistently.

Comment: So what is your question?  Your "working" code isn't capable of infinite precision because `float`s are not capable of infinite precision.  We can't help you with your non-working code that uses `Decimal` because you didn't post it.

Comment: @Jasper So how could I implement that? Would I just put while True and it would work? Or are there other places that need changing?

Comment: Just try it. If you post the code that uses `Decimal` we can perhaps answer your question. But if you use `Decimal` everywhere, it should work just like it works now.

Comment: @roippi I don't want it to be infinitely precise, it would probably crash my computer before it does. I just want it to be more precise than it is at the moment. Also, as for my code using the decimal module, I have no idea how to use it correctly and so I quite literally replaced `float` with `decimal.Decimal`. Help on how to use it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jasper this is what I get when I use while True: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pi7.py", line 12, in <module>
    pi=pi+c
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

Comment: That's quite specific: you are trying to add a `Decimal` and a `float`. `pi` and `c` are of different types.  Please include your actual code in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because the division of two integers results in a float (in Python 3):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> pi = Decimal(3)
>>> a=2
>>> b=a * (a+1) * (a+2)
>>> c=4/b
>>> type(c)
<class 'float'>
>>> pi = pi + c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

The following works:

```
>>> a = Decimal(2)
>>> one = Decimal(1)
>>> b = a * (a+one) * (a+one+one)
>>> c = Decimal(4) / b
>>> type(c)
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
>>> pi = pi + c
>>> pi
Decimal('3.166666666666666666666666667')
```